# Transparency mystery: iframe not transparent in Chrome&IE but Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a simple scenario:

http://jsfiddle.net/akosk/t2KvE/8/

HTML

```
<div id='base'>
    <iframe id="myFrame" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>    
</div>

<script id="content" type="text/html">
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>                                       
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus architecto quasi deleniti eius praesentium non officia culpa corporis officiis perferendis laudantium placeat excepturi. Voluptatum fuga mollitia reiciendis non aliquam dolorem!</h2>              
        </body>
    </html>
</script>
```

JS

```
    var myFrame = $("#myFrame");
    var content = $("#content").html();
    myFrame.contents().find('html').html(content);
```

CSS

```
iframe {
    z-index:0;
    height:100px;
}
#base {
    background-color:red;
    height:100px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

In Chrome & IE **the background color** of iframe is **white instead of the wrapper's color (red)**. In Firefox it works fine.

**Additionally** when inspecting element in Chrome **no HEAD and BODY** nodes in iframe.

**When I remove the css (bootstrap) then everything works fine.**
Somehow if I write anything into HEAD (fe. any css!) the transparency not work and HEAD/BODY tags disappears.

(I tried with * {background-color:transparent} in iframe also without success. I guess the problem is something else)

It's a huge mystery for me.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the following changes in your code

```
//script

var myFrame = $("#myFrame");
var content = $("#content").html();
myFrame.contents().find('body').html(content);
//change html to body here there by setting the content of body
```

css fixes

below the line where the external bootstrap is linked add the following line

```
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <style> BODY {background:none transparent !important}</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank You! The key was: ".find('body')" instead of .find('html'). However it's not perfect because it's put link and style into the body section.
So I split it and first I set head then I set body: http://jsfiddle.net/akosk/t2KvE/57/
It seems I can't put the whole document into the iframe html element  when it has content in head element.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/t2KvE/31/
With simplifying the code I could not reproduce this.

```
iframe {
  height:100px;
}
#base {
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
}
```

Since you added the bootstrap.min.css which sets a white background on the body. You just do

```
iframe body {background-color: transparent;}
```

Therefore it is the body background and not related to the iframe.

Comment: If I remove everything from head then it works fine. Thats why your code works. Try to add anything to the head section it will fail: [http://jsfiddle.net/akosk/t2KvE/58/]

Comment: That is what I am pointing out. The bootstrap CSS added to the head of the iframe has a style body {background: #fff;}. If you do iframe body {background: transparent;} in your main CSS (not the iframe) you override it.